# MySQL DELETE query works except not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a MySQL query to delete 'near' duplicate rows from a table, and while using test data outside of my project, the query appears to work as intended. When I use the same query with PHP in the project, I get an SQL error. I've been trying all sorts of different combinations of quotes and backticks and I can't seem to get this working.

Any idea what is going on here?

**Problem being solved:**
This table sometimes will have rows that are nearly identical, with the only exception being the *as_of_date* column and the total. Only the the most recent date is important, and any older data is no longer needed in this table once newer data comes in.

**Table structure with example data:**

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
| id | account | year | as_of_date  | total |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|  1 |     123 | 2017 | 2017-02-02  |   250 |
|  2 |     123 | 2017 | 2017-11-24  |   790 |
|  3 |     123 | 2018 | 2018-01-30  |    55 |
|  4 |     456 | 2016 | 2016-04-04  |   500 |
|  5 |     456 | 2016 | 2016-10-10  |   300 |
|  6 |     456 | 2017 | 2017-03-12  |    44 |
|  7 |     789 | 2015 | 2015-12-23  |  2000 |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```

**Expected Outcome:**
The desired result is to delete all 'near-duplicate' rows in the table except for the most recent one (*as_of_date*). So there should only be at most 1 row for any given *account* and *year*. The table should look like this after the query is executed:

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
| id | account | year | as_of_date  | total |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|  2 |     123 | 2017 | 2017-11-24  |   790 |
|  3 |     123 | 2018 | 2018-01-30  |    55 |
|  5 |     456 | 2016 | 2016-10-10  |   300 |
|  6 |     456 | 2017 | 2017-03-12  |    44 |
|  7 |     789 | 2015 | 2015-12-23  |  2000 |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```

**The query:**

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM `my_table` AS t
           WHERE t.as_of_date NOT IN (
               SELECT MAX(as_of_date)
               FROM (SELECT * FROM `my_table`) AS t2
               WHERE t2.account = t.account AND t2.year = t.year
               GROUP BY account, `year`
           )";
```

**Here is the SQL error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS t
>                       WHERE t.as_of_date NOT IN (
>                         S' at line 1

Comment: The manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html specifically states *"If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table: `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...`"*

Comment: `DELETE t FROM...` as I quoted the manual above on how to do this.

Comment: The error seems to refer to a column recent_date which isn't in the SQL statement.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, thank you for your comments, that got me a little closer. I did leave a comment for the second edit btw. I changed some of the column names and realized that I did not change the one in the error as Nigel Ren pointed out.

Comment: "while using test data outside of my project, the query appears to work as intended".  So when you run the query given above directly against your DB (using command line, phpmyadmin, MySQL Workbench, whatever), you're saying that it actually works??

Comment: @PatrickQ I created a database locally with that basic schema above, I populated it with some sample data and that query it works using Sequel Pro. I have MySQL Workbench too, but I haven't tried it with that.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but I find it hard to believe that you have the exact query as above working.  Copy/paste, 100% the same, and it's working?  I'm sorry, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @PatrickQ Actually, I think you might be right, because I can't get it to run without error when I try again. I know it worked as SELECT * instead of a DELETE, and I could have sworn that I had this working with DELETE as well, but I guess not. FunkFortyNiner's suggestion worked and the query works as expected. I read the documentation, but I still do not fully understand this syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use table aliases in `DELETE FROM`.  That is, try `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE...`, omitting `AS t`.

By the way, the only times you really need backticks are when you have table names that are the same as reserved words or have spaces in them.

```
  SELECT * FROM `SELECT`
```

or

```
  SELECT * FROM `My Favorite Table`
```

Wise programmers avoid those situations.